# Exclude current vim buffer from buffer list

Tags: buffers, nvim

I am creating a plugin in vim that involves having a sidebar, within which you can switch between several different buffers with different functions. I am wondering how to hide these buffers from the buffer list (when you type :buffers or :ls) so as not to clutter the buffer list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try making the buffer unlisted with `:set nobl` (see `:h 'buflisted'`). This is a buffer local setting so it only affects the current buffer.

Unlisted buffers don't show up with `:ls` by default (see below).

Not sure if this will work with what you have in mind for your plugin as you didn't provide a lot of details. But the basic requirement would be fulfilled.

You can list such buffers by adding `!` to `:ls` or by adding `u`, i.e. `:ls!` or `:ls u`. The latter shows *only* unlisted buffers. You can edit an unlisted buffer by switching to it using `:b #` where `#` is its buffer number. From there you can revert to listed status with `:set bl`.

Comment: with `set hidden`, `:ls h` is kind of like what OP wants maybe?

Comment: @Mass I'm not sure. Would that be flexible enough to work for both users that don't have 'hidden' set as a rule and those that do (myself included)? Maybe I'm not understanding the advantage vs unlisted...

Comment: (I'm assuming OP is creating a plugin for public use.)

Comment: True.  I think though, if I were creating a plugin, I would use a for loop and bufwinid()

Comment: Yeah, because I'm unsure of certain things like what exactly they want to do or how experienced of a coder they are this answer is not offered with any high degree of certainty or definitiveness (that's a real word, I looked it up ;) I  think it's worth mentioning the idea of unlisted buffers, though.\[]

Comment: Thank you for your help. `:set nobl` is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Prismavoid Good to hear. When you get an answer or answers to your question there's something you should do next. In short, voting and accepting. This will provide the details: https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers  (This is how people thank each other around here.) Cheers.

Comment: @BLayer Thanks for the advice! Unfortunately, as this is my first post on the vim stack exchange I do not have enough points to vote, but I have accepted your answer.

Comment: @Prismavoid Oh, yes, that slipped my mind. No big deal. Thanks for the accept! And welcome to Vi&Vim SE. Cheers.